# How to structure web requests for dynamic content that must be consistent

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a dynamically generated HTML page that contains a dynamically generated image (jpeg).  It's important for my application that both of these dynamically generated resources are consistent with one another.  (The HTML contains some elements that I overlay on-top of the image.)  This is a little bit tricky since both resources are fetched in different HTTP requests of course.

What is the best way to structure this in my server code?  Does play support something specific to handle this?

---

A few options spring to mind:

The first is to calculate the parameters for the image during the request for the HTML page, and to place these parameters into the URL for the image.  Unfortunately for me there is quite a bit of state here that I don't think will fit into the URL.

An alternative might be to generate the image (or just the parameters for it) during the request for the HTML, and to stash it server-side somewhere.  Then when the image request comes along I can return the pre-generated image.  The only problem with this solution is that I'd now need to worry about the lifetime of the generated image server-side, which feels yucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your both approaches are correct, anyway I would choose the first one: reason is simple if your request will die for any reason before rendering the page, you'll loose some resources for rendering image, that will be never used. Other thing is that it (probably) should be able to render images from any request not only from controller (as described in second approach), so it's better to create an action able to render it basing on request params.

Conclusion (note, it's just my guessing) - probably you are able to encode all required params into single string (ie. divided by some char, like: `1234_w600_h200.jpg`, which means: get image from database where ID of record is `1234` and create a thumbnail with `width 600px` and `height 200px`. Or even simpler (afaik flicker uses this) `1234s.jpg`, `1234m.jpg`, `1234l.jpg`, where `s`, `m`, `l` appendixes stands for some predefined thumbnails sizes.

So finally all you need to pass from controller to the view is first part - ID of the DB record, other parts (dimensions) you can add directly in the view and you can do it as required... for an example: ***download Small, Medium or Large version ...***